# My get function isn't working

Tags: c++, get

```
class Cat {
public:
    string getname() const;
    void setname(string name);

private:
    string name;
    // constructor
    Cat(string name) {

        this->name = name;
        cout<<"Cat's name is "<< name << endl;
    }
};

int main Cat::getname() {

    string name ="Assignment 09";
    cout << name << endl;
    Dog fido("Fido");
    Cat spot("Spot");
    cout <<"From main, the Dog's name is "<< fido.name << endl;
    cout <<"From main, the Cat's name is "<< spot.name << endl;

    cout <<"Hit any key to continue"<< endl;

    system("pause");

    return name;
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Paul Merimee Try to type the code the same way as it is shown in the book you are reading.

Comment: The top part got cut off.  Is this a class or a struct?

Comment: You should be getting syntax error because `int main Cat::getname() {` is invalid syntax.

Comment: what is your problem?state it clearly

Comment: @ThomasMatthews how would I fix that?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's a class.

Comment: You made your constructor private, which means nobody can use it.

Comment: The syntax for the `main` function is `int main(void)`.  I don't know what you are trying to do with the `Cat::getname()` after the `main` function name.  So remove the `Cat::getname` from the `main` function declaration.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm trying to get the string name.

Answer (score 0):

To get the name from your objects, you will need to use the `getname` method:

```
// Note the removal of Cat::getname()
int main (void)
{

    string name ="Assignment 09";
    cout << name << endl;
    Dog fido("Fido");
    Cat spot("Spot");

    // Note the changes here:  fido.getname()
    cout <<"From main, the Dog's name is "<< fido.getname() << endl;

    // Similarly:  spot.getname()
    cout <<"From main, the Cat's name is "<< spot.getname() << endl;

    cout <<"Hit any key to continue"<< endl;

    system("pause");

    return name;
}
```

The `fido.getname()` is an assumption because you did not provide the class definition for `Dog` in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Except I'm still getting this [IntelliSense: "Dog::Dog(std::string name)" (declared at line 15) is inaccessible] error. How would I fix this?

Comment: Use your crystal ball to see my answer or post the definition of your `Dog` class.  Hint:  Is the constructor in the `private`, `protected` or `public` section in your class?

Comment: Here's my dog class.
class Dog {

 public:

  string getname;

  string name;

 private:

 // constructor

 Dog(static string name) {
      
  this->name = name;

  cout <<"Dog's name is "<< name << endl;

 }

};

Comment: Try again.  **Edit Your Question** and place the definition there.  Don't put code in comments because it is hard to read (can you easily read the code in your comment?).

Comment: The constructor is private.

Comment: Remember, that methods in the `private` section can only be accessed by the object and *not external entities*.  So the `main` function, being an external entity to `Dog`, is not allowed to access the `private` parts of the `Dog`.  Since the constructor is `private`, the `main` function can't access the constructor and thus cannot construct the object.

Comment: Would I be able to construct it in the constructor and then access it from main?

Comment: You should take the simple route and move your constructor from the `private` section to the `public` section.

Comment: I wish I could do this. This is an assignment and I'm supposed to access a variable from a private section.

Comment: The constructor is not a variable but a method or function.  Your `Dog` and `Cat` classes should look very similar.  Talk to your instructor if your confused about where the constructors should be placed.